# Does Aptana 3 provide a PHP plugin as good as Aptana 1.5.1?

Tags: php, aptana

Has anyone tried out Aptana 3?  Does its PHP plugin suck as much as it did with 2.0?  Still running Aptana 1.5.1 here...

Comment: It's not a plugin anymore as it's built into Aptana 3. Works great out of the box for what I need

Answer (score 2):

It's all built in. Aptana Studio 3 is a great tool although from experience is a bit buggy when working on large projects.

Comment: I'll give it a shot!  Hopefully it has nice code completion and function hinting like the aptana php 1.1 plugin.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty decent in that respect, I haven't had much luck with class hinting, but my project is fairly dynamic.. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Aptana 3 PHP Plugin is rubbish...
The usability is worse then Aptana 1.5

Comment: I disagree pretty strongly with this answer. I use Aptana Studio 3 for 8 hours a day doing PHP, and I have yet to find a better IDE.

Comment: I have been a long time user of Aptana (since version 1), and long time ago I tried the "Aptana 3 PHP Plugin". Rubbish indeed, when compared to version 1.5. If you never used the v1.5 plugin, then you will not see anything bad with v3, so feel free to use v3.
But for those that miss v1.5 PHP Plugin, here's a link to downgrade: http://www.bram.us/2010/01/26/installing-the-original-aptana-15-php-plugin-in-aptana-20/

Comment: @BrendonDugan, nothing compares to PhpStorm.

Comment: @AlexanderMP Over the last two years I have come to the same conclusion.