# Does Aptana Studio 3 support launching or previewing PHP applications?

Tags: php, aptana, aptana3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Aptana 3 provide a PHP plugin as good as Aptana 1.5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540343/does-aptana-3-provide-a-php-plugin-as-good-as-aptana-1-5-1)

I want to ask if **Aptana studio 3** supports PHP? 
I'm writing a program and trying to run it, but nothing happens when I press the "Run" button. I get the message `"The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches."` What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have Apache set up? If not, download WAMP Server.

Comment: I have installed Apache but I still cannot run a php project.I take the message:The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches.Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

When you are setting up the server (Window > Preferences > Web servers > New...) you need to chose "External Web Server", instead of "Simple Web Server". Enter the Name, Base URL and Document root as usual. Then for Start command enter NET START wampapache and for Stop command NET STOP wampapache. Once you set the Run command to use this server setup, it should work. (Well, it does for me, anyway.)